# Solr streaming expression - join multivalued field

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Tried joining two collections (collection1, collection2) using below streaming expression query.

hashJoin(search(Collection1,q="*:*",fl="id",sort="id asc",rows=1000),hashed=cartesianProduct(search(Collection2,q="Name:microsoft",fl="Name,Key",sort="Name asc",rows=100),Key),on="id=Key")

```
Collection1
    id      String
Collection2
    Name    String
    Key     Multivalued
```

It does come back with results, but it doesn't show results from Collection2 where Key is null in Collection1 (which is the requirement).
Would appreciate your inputs.

Comment: If you are using solr streaming for retrieving the fields from 2 different collection then you need have the docValues as true and multivalued as false. Also fields cannot be tokenised.

Comment: The call to `cartesianProduct` circumvents the requirement for multivalued="false" - it expands the multivalued field into separate rows for each value in the field. But instead of `hashJoin` - it seems you're looking for [outerHashJoin](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/stream-decorators.html#outerhashjoin) instead of plain hashJoin? (you might have to swap your collections around so the join happens from Collection2 towards Collection1 instead)